no exists method build
i have this entity
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "refresh_tokens")
public class RefreshToken {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String token;

    private Instant expiryDate;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private long userId;

    //getters and setters...
}

and in service RefreshTokenService i have method
public RefreshToken createRefreshToken(String username){
        RefreshToken refreshToken = RefreshToken.builder()
                .userInfo(userRepository.findByUsername(username))
                .token(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .expiryDate(Instant.now().plusMillis(600000)) // set expiry of refresh token to 10 minutes - you can configure it application.properties file
                .build();
        return refreshTokenRepository.save(refreshToken);
    }

but method build() not exists, but i written annotation @Builder in entity
i realy idk

What type does RefreshToken.builder() return and what methods does it have? Does your project compile outside the IDE (via maven for instance)?
